# On the Server: Getting IP Address of Connected Clients

Tags: c#, .net, sockets

I've two machines: Server & Client
when I ask for the client ip in the client machine by

```
TcpClient client = new TcpClient();
client.Connect(serverip, PORTNO);
MessageBox.Show(client.Client.LocalEndPoint.ToString());
```

I get: 192.168.241.128:1025
It's the client ip.

but when I apply on the server the following:

```
_client = client;
_clientIP = client.Client.RemoteEndPoint.ToString();
AllClients.Add(_clientIP, this);
data = new byte[_client.ReceiveBufferSize];
_client.GetStream().BeginRead(data, 0, System.Convert.ToInt32(_client.ReceiveBufferSize), ReceiveMessage, null);

MessageBox.Show(client.Client.RemoteEndPoint.ToString());
```

I get 192.168.92.1:1047
which is the server ip!

What's the problem?

Comment: Have you tried reconnecting? Maybe clear your Bin folder and rebuild?

Comment: When you run it from the server, what are you connecting to?

it seems as if you are connecting from the server TO the server, so both endpoints will have the same ip with different ports

Comment: I'm connecting from a vmware os(XP) (which is the client)

Comment: The main os is the server

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking. If you have two different machine, they will have two different IP address.  What is the result are you expecting?

Comment: @BlackFrog He wants to get 192.168.241.128 in RemoteEndPoint

Comment: @user3379482 can you please add the code on the server where you accept the connection from the client.

Comment: Then why do I get a different ip when I ask for the localEndPoint in the client fron the server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That happend to me one day...
the problem is using vmware!
when I tried to connect to a real network...I got the correct IP's
Try to do it with a real network!